# Python 4b gateway

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, payment

I'm developing a web app in django, and I will need to interface with 4b payment gateway. I know that there are sermepa apps for python (sermepa is another common gateway) or PayPal ones, but can't find nothing about 4b.

Anyone can tell me if there is any gateway plugin, app, or something written in python (or even better, a django app) for 4b gateway?

Thanks in advance,

Isaac

Answer (score 0):

It appears that someone has written [a Django app for Pasat 4B which can be found on Github](https://github.com/zikzakmedia/django-pasat4b) - apparently it's in a similar style to django-paypal and django-sermepa, according to the README.